# data.table - summarizing data - difference between `by` and `keyby`?

Tags: r, data.table

I have notice that the following two commands yield very different results, so I was wondering what the difference is ?

```
TestData <- TestData[, keyby = c("group","date"), 
                             .(totalCount = sum(count))]

TestData <- TestData[, by = c("group","date"), 
                             .(totalCount = sum(count))]
```

according to the cheatsheet:

> dt[, j, by = .(a)] – group rows by values in specified columns.

and

> dt[, j, keyby = .(a)] – group and simultaneously sort rows by values
>   in specified columns.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using `keyby` rather than `by` will make result rows ordered by the columns you are grouping on.
Otherwise when using `by` the row order of results is retained as the order of the groups in input data.
Having ordered data can speed up some further computations on that. On the other hand having original order might be required by user. In most cases `keyby` will be slightly faster than `by`.

Comment: Perfect answer. Just one additional comment: It not only orders the data but also sets a key on the respective variables, which enables fast binary search in comparison to traditional vector scans. See https://rdatatable.gitlab.io/data.table/articles/datatable-keys-fast-subset.html#binary-search-vs-vector-scans on that